# Cannot connect SharePoint Online to Visual Studio 2013

Tags: sharepoint-online, visual-studio-2013

I am a beginner in SharePoint O365 and I am trying to create an event handler using VS2013.

I followed these steps:

1. file >> new >> project
2. Office/SharePoint >> Apps >> Apps for SharePoint

When I tried to add new item "Remote Event Receiver", this message appeared

[image]

and no popup message appeared so I can enter my username and password in O365.

What shall I do to solve this problem?!